# Error while constructing an object mentioning another type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The compiler constantly shows the following errors referring to a different class constructor prototype. `Point2D` is another class which is used to construct the `Line2D` object.

> C:\Users*****\src\Line2D.cpp|3|error: no matching function for call to 'Point2D::Point2D()'
>   include\Point2D.h|13|note: candidate: Point2D::Point2D(int, int)|

```
//this file(Line2D.h) has #include "Point2D.h"
Line2D(Point2D ,Point2D ); // constructor prototype

//this file(Line2D.cpp) has #include "Line2D.h"
Line2D::Line2D(Point2D pt1,Point2D pt2) // ERROR ON THIS LINE constructor method 
{
    this -> pt1 = pt1;
    this -> pt2 = pt2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the issue is that your constructor is using a default constructor for `Point2D` that doesn't exist.

Use initialization lists:

```
Line2D::Line2D(Point2D pt1,Point2D pt2):pt1(pt1), pt2(pt2){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the implementation for  default constructor for `Point2D` class.

```
Point2D::Point2D()
```